# How to remove English Words from a column in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, nltk

Very new to Python.

Problem: I have a csv file that contains rows with alpha-numeric text, and I want to remove all English words. For example, an input is: "Steam traps on Steam to 56X-233 Butane Vaporizer"
and the desired output is just: "56X-233"

Is the answer like removing stop words with NLTK?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to refer to the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098) before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about matching actual words you can use a regex to match any word with no numbers in it:

```py
import re

def remove_words(line):
    # Remove words containing only letters
    line = re.sub(r"\b[A-Za-z]+\b", "", line)

    # Remove remaining extra spaces
    return re.sub(" +", " ", line).strip()

print(remove_words("Steam traps on Steam to 56X-233 Butane Vaporizer"))
```

To do this to an entire file, you just need to grab each line of the file and run the above code on it:

```py
with open("my_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(remove_words(line))
```

Comment: You can combine both of these regexes into `r"\b[A-Za-z]+\b"` using the "word boundary" marker.

Comment: Alternately, you could search for what you _do_ want, eg "any word containing at least one digit" would be `r"\w*\d\w*"`

Comment: Hey this is great stuff, all of these. The one last I need to do is do it for 500,000 lines in the .csv file. Is there a easy way to input a file, as oppose to a string?

Comment: Updated the answer with the combined regex + how to integrate a file

Comment: Awesome thank you. Since I am still getting the hand of stackoverflow, What do I do to say this answers my question?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow